# Ldap_add() : Invalid Syntax

Tags: php, ldap, syntax-error

I have a program here that uses the ldap_add,
when i try to run the program, it displays an 
error:

> Warning: ldap_add() [function.ldap-add]: Add: Invalid syntax in
>   /var/www/suey/costcenter.20090617.php on line 780

My lil' code here is:

```
 $ldapservers = 'ourServer';
 $ds = ldap_connect($ldapservers);
 if ($ds) {
     $r = ldap_bind($ds, $ldaprootun, $ldaprootpw);
     $add = ldap_add($ds, "uid=$fuid, $ldapbasedn", $infonew);
 }
```

ldapbasedn is set to `o=ourGroup;` infonew is an array of entries (person information)
and am so sure that the array is not empty because i already tested it.
the uid is not empty too.
What could be wrong? Is it the entries(array)? or the server am trying to connect to?
I tried testing the ldap_bind, and it also works well too..hmmm..

Pls help.. thanks!

---

I found the problem.. it's in the index infonew["createdBy"] = getenv("REMOTE_USER");
it returns NULL! now, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post a `var_dump($infonew)` (or `print_r($infonew)`)?

I strongly assume that there is some data in `$infonew` that cannot be written to the LDAP server.

**EDIT:**

You cannot use `null` in the LDAP data array. Either strip the appropriate key (`createdBy`) from the array or set the value to `array()`.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same error and when looking closer I saw that it was caused by having a null cn field.